# troubles connecting to a (remote) PostgreSQL database using FireDAC & Delphi 10.3.3

Tags: postgresql, delphi, firedac

Using Delphi 10.3.3 I need to access a Postgress database on a remote server. I am trying using FireDac. I am not able to connect to the remote database, so I thought to create a testprog and a local PostgreSQL-database first. So I installed PostgreSQL 32 bit on my machine. Copied the libpq.dll to the same location as my exe, copied the libpq.dll to Windows\System32 as well. Checked the PATH, System32 is there. But still I get "Cannot load vendor library (libpq.dll). The specified module could not be found"

I tried 64 bit versions as well, I found different versions of the libpq.dll which I tried without success.

Do you have any experience in how to solve this ? 
If you have the latest libpq.dll, does the remote database version matter ? I am new to PostgreSQL, how can I find the version ?

Answer (score 1):

Just libpq.dll is not enough, you need other DLLs. You will find the full list [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Connect_to_PostgreSQL_(FireDAC)).